# How to convert Zend Framework getResultRowObject to array

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
public function loginAction() {

   $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();    

   $DB = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
   $request=$this->getRequest();        

   $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($DB);
   $authAdapter->setTableName('user')
               ->setIdentityColumn('uname')
               ->setCredentialColumn('password');  

   $uname = $request->getParam('uname');
   $pass = $request->getParam('password');

   $authAdapter->setIdentity($uname);
   $authAdapter->setCredential($pass);

   $result = $authAdapter->authenticate($authAdapter);
   $this->view->assign('auth',$result);
   if($result->isValid()) {

       $data = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null,'pass');
       $auth->getStorage()->write($data);

       //$this->view->assign('dbdata',$data);

       $userInfo = new Zend_Session_Namespace('userInfo');
       $userInfo->userType = 'admin';

       //$this->_redirect('/admin/adminhome');
   } else {

       $this->_redirect('/admin/index?fail=true');
   }    

   $data = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null,'pass');
```

Here the `$data` will return an object like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [uname] => user [password] => user [type] => user )
```

I want to convert this to an array. Just tried `toArray()` function but in vain. My requirement is to check user type like this:

```
if($data['type']=='admin'){
do something
} else {
do something 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, use:

```
$data = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null,'pass');
$anArray = (array) $data;
```

Or more simply:

```
$data = (array) $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null,'pass');
```

But you don't need to convert to an array. Just use the object directly:

```
$data = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null,'pass');
if($data->type=='admin'){
do something
} else{
do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
$array = get_object_vars($data);
```

For multidimensional arrays you need to wrap it in functon:

```
function toArray($data) {
  if (is_object($data)) {
    $data = get_object_vars($data);
  }
  if (is_array($data)) {
    return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $data);
  } else {
    return $d;
  }
}
```